# How do I add whitespace using GWT 2.4 and uiBinder?

Tags: css, gwt, layout, whitespace, uibinder

I'm working on doing my layout using HTMLPanel in uiBinder.

I want to create some whitespace, lets say 70px of height, in several places on the page, to split up the vertical layout of the widgets.

What is the preferred way to do this?  Using CSS or a panel that isn't visible or some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS.  You can write it right at the top of your ui.xml file.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World

Comment: I did use a FlowPanel, but that seemed clunky, using CSS works well.  Thanks!